# From Python to Java: Proper while loop declaration

Tags: java, python, type-conversion, greatest-common-divisor

How do I write this code in Java?

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """
    Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.
    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

It seems I can't do `while (b) {` in Java because of `Type mismatch` error. It seems I also can't do the line `a, b = b, a%b` exactly in Java as well.

Comment: Why not grab a book on Java. These are the basics, you will learn in the first couple of chapters of any book.

Comment: @RohitJain got any book recommendations?

Comment: @user1757703 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: There are so many out there in the market. You can start with Bruce Eckel's - Thinking in Java. Or try http://www.google.com

Comment: `while b` -> `while (b != 0)`. `a,b = b, a%b` -> `tmp = b; b=a%b;a=tmp`.

Comment: Certainly a book or tutorial, *any*, will be a much more efficient way to learn java than to guess/stumble/post/guess/stumble/post... etc...

Comment: If you're curious why this doesn't work in Java: most types cannot be coerced to `boolean` (the `while b` part) and there is no analogue for tuple unpacking (the `a,b = ...` part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        int temp;
        while(b != 0) {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp % b;
        }
        return a;
}
```

Java expects the condition of the `while` to be a boolean, not an `int`.

The `a, b = b, a%b` syntax will not work in Java.  You need to do the assignments individually.

So you can set `a = b`, and then set `b = a % b`.  I used a temp variable to hold the old value of `a` so that I can compute `a % b` (before I overwrote `a` with `a = b`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a *while*? It can be as simple as-

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {

   if (b == 0) return a;

   return gcd(b, a % b);

}
```

Comment: Note that as this code looks simpler - as it is shorter - it is not more efficient than using the "while". In languages not optimized for this, such as lisp or scheme, function calling will use a lot more system resources than the interactive equivalent.

Comment: @jsbueno Well..jh314 answered that before me. So I wanted to show another way since I was here already. :)